# Entity Reference returns blank

Tags: nodes

I have a content type where users upload a file. An administrator then uses a select list which is an [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) that assigns the node to another user with a specific role. They do there work on the file and upload their work. The issue is, when the second user saves the node the entity reference gets blanked. Using version 7.51

How can I insure that the field stays populated through the whole process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module and only allow admin to edit and view value for the entity reference field.

Comment: I am using the Field Permissions module, and the referenced user does not have permission to view the entity reference field.